# State is empty after parsing data to it

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to fetch data from my local json file.
Fetching the data don't give errors and everything is returning correctly in a console log.
When I try to set that data into a state, it works if I parse json and not json.data.
json.data don't do anything, but json works, only if I use the map function it gives me a bunch of errors

Code :

```
getData = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/ingredients.json')
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response;
                } else {
                    let response = `${response.statusText}`
                    let errorMessage = `${response.status(response)}`
                    let error = new Error(errorMessage)
                    throw (error)
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json);
                this.setState({ data: json })
                console.log(this.state)
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.data &&
                    this.state.data.map((key, display, nutrition) =>
                        <div key={key}>
                            {display}
                            {nutrition}
                        </div>
                    )}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Here are my error :

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {key, display, unity, category, nutrition, vitamins}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: in which format u get ur data? i think its in object form which is not support in map so u have to change the format of ur return data

Comment: @sayalok yes my json file is 1 big object, but how do I do it then? Or how do I return it as an array?

Comment: Error says that your data is not array, it is object. Map function can be used with arrays.

Comment: instead of using map u have to loop through all ur data inside func and pass it to ur render . i have an example for it as soon as i find it i will share it to u . till then u can keep trying

Comment: I changed my json in an array, linted it and it's valid, but now I got Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token { in JSON at position 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` function of `Array.prototype` accepts a function callback with args, `(value, index) => {}`. If you plan is to destructure, use instead

```
this.state.data.map({key, display, nutrition, ...rest}, index) => { // index of value in this.sta
 <div key={key}>
   {display} //I am assuming this is a string not a object or array
   {nutrition} // this should be a string 
 </div>
}
```

**Edit**: 
I am assuming `data` is like

```
data: [
 {
   key: "",
   nutrition: "",
   display: ""
 }, 
 {
   key: "",
   nutrition: "",
   display: ""
 } 
]
```

**Edit 2**:

Given this

```
state {
data = 
 [
    { id: 1, 
        display: 'Pommes', 
        unity: [ 'unités' ], 
        category: [ 'fruits' ], 
        nutrition: 95, 
        vitamins: [ 'C', 'B-6' ] 
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        display: 'Poires',
        unity: [ 'unités' ],
        category: [ 'fruits' ],
        nutrition: 95,
        vitamins: [ 'C', 'B', 'E' ]
    }
];
}
```

Here is how to display it:

```
render() {
   return (
     <>
      {
       this.state.data && this.state.data.map(({id, display, nutrition, vitamins}) => {
          return (
           <div key={id}>
            {display} 
            {nutrition}
            {<>vitamins.map(v => v) </>} //in case you need thing such as vitamis, Array, also to eppear
          </div>
        )})
      }
     </>

   )
}
```

Comment: This won't realy work since nutrition and some other stuff in there are objects

Comment: Thus, `Objects are not valid as a React child `

Comment: @TristanVermeesch `nutrition` is a number and display is a string based on your comment on @mstfyldz 's answer. For array values, use map to display them, see **Edit 2**

Comment: Oh like that, ok I understand that. Sorry I'm pretty new to react.
I have this now, probably just a little error : Your render method should have return statement
 @tbuglc

Comment: Just extracted needed code but yeah I can include that too

Comment: let me make a pen for you quickly

Comment: @TristanVermeesch please check this sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/0x96zkpznl

Of course I can't render your values because localhost:3000 can't be reached from there

Comment: Thanks for that, I understand it a bit more now.
Still got this error : Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
EDIT: Problem fixed, port changed

Comment: @TristanVermeesch is there any clue from react such as line of code of something?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not array don't use map function. Change your code like below:

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.data &&
                        <div key={this.state.data.key}>
                            {this.state.data.display}
                            {this.state.data.nutrition}
                        </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: I literray just tried that before you post it ;)
But still for some reasons it don't show the content, no errors

Comment: Like, how does this work? You're not mapping anything so how can it output everything?

Comment: because map is used with arrays and you said that your data is object. Can you post your data content so I can help you.

Comment: Here is my data = 
```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "display": "Pommes",
        "unity": [
            "unités"
        ],
        "category": [
            "fruits"
        ],
        "nutrition": 95,
        "vitamins": [
            "C",
            "B-6"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "display": "Poires",
        "unity": [
            "unités"
        ],
        "category": [
            "fruits"
        ],
        "nutrition": 95,
        "vitamins": [
            "C",
            "B",
            "E"
        ]
    }
]
```